# Debugging access violation error: writing to 2071E05A0 instead of 3071E05A0

Tags: fortran, fortran77, silverfrost-fortran

### Final edit:

Some users on the silverfrost forums directed me very helpfully, to a simplification of the code and a solution.

The issue can be replicated using the following code:

```
      PROGRAM ML14ERROR   
        INTEGER :: origzn, destzn
        INTEGER,PARAMETER :: MXZMA = 1713, LXTZN = 1714, MXAV = 182
        INTEGER,PARAMETER :: JTMPREL = 1003, av = 1
        REAL(KIND=2) :: RANDOM@
        REAL,dimension (1:mxav,lxtzn,lxtzn,JTMPREL:JTMPREL):: znzndaav

        DO origzn=1,lxtzn
          DO destzn=1,lxtzn
            znzndaav(av,origzn,destzn,JTMPREL) = RANDOM@()
          END DO
        END DO

        DO origzn=1,mxzma
          DO destzn=1,mxzma
            ! This is where the error occurs
            znzndaav(av,origzn,lxtzn,JTMPREL)=
     $         znzndaav(av,origzn,lxtzn,JTMPREL)+
     $         znzndaav(av,origzn,destzn,JTMPREL)

          ENDDO
        ENDDO

        WRITE(6,*)'No errors'
      END PROGRAM
```

The issue only arises when `MXAV`>182, which suggests a memory issue. Indeed, multiplying out the dimensions: 183 * 1714 * 1714 * 4 yields >2GB, exceeding the stack size.

A solution would be to use the heap as follows (Fortan 95):

```
PROGRAM ML14ERROR    
  INTEGER :: origzn, destzn
  INTEGER,PARAMETER :: MXZMA = 1713, LXTZN = 1714, MXAV = 191
  INTEGER,PARAMETER :: JTMPREL = 1003, av = 1
  REAL(KIND=2) :: RANDOM@
  REAL,allocatable :: znzndaav(:,:,:,:)

  ALLOCATE( znzndaav(1:mxav,lxtzn,lxtzn,JTMPREL:JTMPREL) )
  DO origzn=1,lxtzn
    DO destzn=1,lxtzn
      znzndaav(av,origzn,destzn,JTMPREL) = RANDOM@()
    END DO
  END DO

  DO origzn=1,mxzma
    DO destzn=1,mxzma
      ! This is where the error occurs
      znzndaav(av,origzn,lxtzn,JTMPREL)= &
  &         znzndaav(av,origzn,lxtzn,JTMPREL)+ &
  &         znzndaav(av,origzn,destzn,JTMPREL)

    ENDDO
  ENDDO
  DEALLOCATE(znzndaav)
  
  WRITE(6,*)'No errors'
END PROGRAM
```

Once we do this, we can allocate more than 2GB and the array works fine. The program this small section of code stems from is a few years old, and we've only just now run into the issue because a model we've built is many times larger than any before. As Fortran 77 doesn't allow ALLOCATABLE arrays, we must either reduce stack usage, or port the code - or seek another optimisation.

---

### Edited to add:

I have now put together [a git repo which contains reproducible code](https://bitbucket.org/dsc_test/ml14_error_20190731/src/master/).

---

## Overview

I have a program that works fine when compiled to 32-bit, but presents an access violation error when compiled and run in 64-bit.

I'm using the Silverfrost Fortran compiler, FTN95 v8.51, though this issue occurs using v8.40 and v8.50.

---

## Sample code

```
! .\relocmon.inc
      INTEGER JTMPREL
      PARAMETER(JTMPREL=1003)
      REAL znda(lxtzn,JTMPREL:JTMPREL)
      REAL zndaav(1:mxav,lxtzn,JTMPREL:JTMPREL)      
      REAL,dimension (lxtzn,lxtzn,JTMPREL:JTMPREL) :: znznda
      REAL mlrlsum(lxtzn,lxtzn)

      REAL,dimension (1:mxav,lxtzn,lxtzn,JTMPREL:JTMPREL):: znzndaav

      COMMON /DDMON/ znda, znznda, mlrlsum,znzndaav, zndaav
! EOF .\relocmon.inc

! .\relocmon.inc with values
      INTEGER JTMPREL
      PARAMETER(JTMPREL=1003)
      REAL znda(1714,JTMPREL:JTMPREL)
      REAL zndaav(1:191,1714,JTMPREL:JTMPREL)      
      REAL,dimension (1714,1714,JTMPREL:JTMPREL) :: znznda
      REAL mlrlsum(1714,1714)

      REAL,dimension (1:191,1714,1714,JTMPREL:JTMPREL):: znzndaav

      COMMON /DDMON/ znda, znznda, mlrlsum,znzndaav, zndaav
! EOF .\relocmon.inc

! .\main.for
        INCLUDE 'relocmon.inc'
        
        REAL,save,dimension(lxtzn,lxtzn,mxav) :: ddfuncval
        
        DO origzn=1,mxzma
          IF( zonedef(origzn,JZUSE) )THEN
            DO destzn=1,mxzma
              IF (zonedef(destzn,JZUSE)) THEN
                znznda(origzn,destzn,JTMPREL)=znda(destzn,JTMPREL)*
     $                                       ddfuncval(origzn,destzn,av)            

               znznda(origzn,lxtzn,JTMPREL)=znznda(origzn,lxtzn,JTMPREL)
     $               +znznda(origzn,destzn,JTMPREL)
     
         znzndaav(av,origzn,destzn,JTMPREL)=zndaav(av,destzn,JTMPREL)*
     $                                    ddfuncval(origzn,destzn,av)           

         ! LINE 309 -- where error occurs
         znzndaav(av,origzn,lxtzn,JTMPREL)=
     $               znzndaav(av,origzn,lxtzn,JTMPREL)
     $             +znzndaav(av,origzn,destzn,JTMPREL)
     
              ENDIF
            ENDDO
          ENDIF
        ENDDO

! EOF .\main.for
```

NB the function `zonedef` simply checks that a zone is valid for the calculation we want to undertake. This function returns a `logical`.

---

## Debugging

As I mentioned initially, the 32-bit compiled version of this program works fine. When attempting to run the 64-bit version, the output of the first loop is this:

from sdbg64.exe:

```
Error: Access Violation reading address
0x00000002071E05A0

main.for: 309
```

write exception to file:

```
Access violation (c0000005) at address 43a1f4

Within file ml14.exe
in main in line 309, at address 2b84

RAX = 0000000000000001   RBX = 000000027fff704c   RCX = 000000000285e6b8   RDX = 00000002802296cc
RBP = 0000000000400000   RSI = 000000029ba3ad6c   RDI = 0000000307695374   RSP = 000000000285be70
R8  = 0000000307695374   R9  = 00000002ffff5040   R10 = 000000029ba3ad6c   R11 = 000000030731f0dc
R12 = 000000027fff5584   R13 = 00000002802296cc   R14 = 000000028169f3ec   R15 = 0000000281660928

43a1f4) addss       XMM11,[85b401b4++R14]
```

For the rest of this... please bear with me. I'm not a trained software engineer or fortran developer by any stretch, so I'm stabbing in the dark a little to troubleshoot.

The value for `ZNZNDAAV(1,337,337,1003)` is 2.241640, and this is being added to `ZNZNDAAV(1,337,1714,1003)`. This tallies with register XMM11 as detailed in the exception output. This value is at address `000000029BA3BD60`. The other value is at address `00000003071E05A0`.

IIUC, in relocmon.inc we're setting `COMMON /DDMON/` to contain the dimensioned array `znzndaav`, so if the software were working nominally, the address of the value in question would be within the `/DDMON/` block. The address range for `/DDMON/` is `z'000000027FFF6040' - z'0000000307421150'`. If my logic is correct, the violation occurs *outside* of this block.

It appears to me that the program is attempting to write to `00000002071E05A0` when it should be using `00000003071E05A0`.

Can anyone help me determine why this would be the case? There appears to be something systematic about it - could it be mere coincidence?

Comment: I tried to reproduce and failed, i.e. no crash for me. However, I tried on Linux 64-bit using GFortran. You might want to make the repo easier to compile, to get better responses. Since I do not  use whatever IDE you use, I had to go digging into the makefiles to figure out what to compile and how. Hint: Do not use compiler-dependent KIND-numbers.

Comment: Thanks, rtoijala. I'm very new to this: the example I put together was too complex for the issue at hand - had I have reduced it down, I would have seen the root cause of the error very quickly. Please see latest edit to question.